# Android - Proguard - data protection

Tags: android, security, encryption, proguard

I am new to Proguard in Android and thought of asking a question to the community. If I am setting minify and shrink to true, in the app gradle (module), would that secure any constants that I might have defined in a Java class?

For example:

```
public class References
{
    public static final long RESEND_TIME_LIMIT = 60L;
    public static final int MAX_RESEND = 3;
}
```

Now, if I set the below in my module level gradle file:

```
buildTypes 
{
    release {
        minifyEnabled true   // Obfuscate and minify codes
        shrinkResources true // Remove unused resources
        useProguard true     // Remove unused codes
        debuggable false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```

Now, will this secure the constants that I have defined? I mean, would someone with root level access to the device, could change the values somehow?

Please help me understand. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Proguard not secure code 100 percent. it's change class and variable name.it's not change value of constant you define.

To secure your constant you have to use native c++ library. for more details refer this [doc](https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/add-native-code).